# Jstl problem, jasperException uri not found

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, jstl

i have a problem with JSTL, i'm using Eclipse ide and created a new Web-application project version 2.5

I have downloaded the `jstl-1.2.jar` which contains both jstl1.1 and standard jars, and properly added in the libraries of my project.

The way i'm referencing the taglib is:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

as specified by the `c.tld` file:

```
      <description>JSTL 1.1 core library</description>
  <display-name>JSTL core</display-name>
  <tlib-version>1.1</tlib-version>
  <short-name>c</short-name>
  <uri>http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core</uri>
```

Eclipse does not underline anything in red or does not give any warning so the taglib reference is fine, i dont know though, why, wenever i run the project i get the following error:

> The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Well thats not true because that uri is in the `c.tld` file which is one of the files used to deploy the application.

Now to be honest, this works fine in another IDE which i wont mention for market-related reasons, is just that i want it to work in eclipse as well.

do you have any advice?

Comment: It works fine for me with jstl.jar on the classpath.

Comment: i assume you also have the 'standard.jar' in your classpath? if i try with standard.jar and jstl.jar i have to change the taglib reference uri in "http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" but still, same error appears

Comment: You don't need standard.jar with JSTL 1.2.

Comment: i know, indeed i tried both options, jstl1.2 alone and jstl+standard, same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had just to drop the JAR file in `/WEB-INF/lib`, not elsewhere and then fiddle with buildpath.

See also our [JSTL tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info).